# TypeScript: typeof T not compatible with { new(): T }

Tags: typescript

I'm wondering why the types `typeof T`and `new() => T` aren't compatible. Consider a `getConstructor<T>` function:

```
function getConstructor<T>( instance: T )
{
    return instance.constructor as new() => T;
}

let instance = new MyClass();
let x: typeof MyClass;
let y = getConstructor( instance );
x = y; // type error
```

The error states: Type `new () => MyClass` is not assignable to type `typeof MyClass`. It occurs probably because my `MyClass` has some static functions that are missing in `new() => MyClass`.

So a solution would be to use `typeof T`:

```
function getConstructor<T>( instance: T )
{
    return instance.constructor as typeof T; // type error
}
```

This, however, gives me another type error: `T` only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.

The TypeScript language specifications states in section 4.18.6:
In positions where a type is expected, 'typeof' can also be used in a type query [...] to produce
the type of an expression.

So why does the above type error occur? And is there some way to make this work, anyway?

Comment: Could you share a link to basic code of the first example in TypeScript Playground? http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your confusion stems from the fact that `MyClass` is both the name of a *type* (which only TypeScript knows about and gets erased at runtime) and the name of a *value* (which is a JavaScript object that exists at runtime).  The *type* `MyClass` applies to instances of the class, while the *value* `MyClass` is a constructor.

TypeScript allows you to query the types of *values* with the `typeof` operator.  So, `typeof MyClass` is referring to the type of the constructor of `MyClass`.  You can't query the type of *types*, so, for example, `typeof string` is an error (unless there's conincidentally a variable named `string`).  So you can't do `typeof T` where `T` is some type.

---

I haven't found a *great* way to give you what you want.  TypeScript doesn't know how to infer the exact type of the `constructor` property from an instance.  It just thinks it's `Function`.  The best I could do is explicitly mark class declarations as having a `constructor` of the right type.  Like so:

```
interface Constructable<T, C extends Constructor<T>> {
  "constructor": C
}

class MyClass implements Constructable<MyClass, typeof MyClass> {
  "constructor" = MyClass;
  // static methods, etc;
}

function getConstructor<C extends Constructor<{}>>(instance: Constructable<{},C> )
{
  return instance.constructor;
}

let instance = new MyClass();
let x: typeof MyClass;
let y = getConstructor(instance);
x = y; // no error
```

Not sure if you can do that to your classes. Hope that helps.  Good luck!